# Voltage graph of capacitor with AC source

Tags: capacitor, diodes

below is the 'Dickson's charge pump'. What I want to know is that when clk is on, why does Vx is 3v instead of 1v? I just thought Vin contribute 2v to cap, clk contribute 1v to cap, so 2v - 1v = 1v but it isn't. Could you explain this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's approach this by analyzing what happens as Vclk cycles between 0V and 1V. Assume you just turned on Vin and Vclk, so no charge has been built up yet. Namely, the two capacitors are "empty", meaning they have 0V across them. We'll also assume the diodes are ideal.

**Step 1**:
Vclk is initially low. If the left capacitor has no voltage across it, both sides of the capacitor are at the same potential: 0V. The left diode is forward biased because there are 2V at its anode and 0V at its cathode. Therefore current begins to flow through the diode and charging the left capacitor (initially, the current flows through the right diode as well and charges both caps, but that's not important right now). Since there's no resistance in this circuit, the capacitor charges very fast. By the time Vclk jumps up to 1V, the capacitor is fully charged to 2V across its plates.

**Step 2**:
Vclk jumps up to 1V. A useful property of capacitors is that the voltage across its plates will be preserved even if the source it's connected to suddenly changes. So if the voltage on the bottom of the capacitor suddenly jumps to 1V, the 2V difference across the capacitor is preserved, and the top plate jumps up to 3V. The left diode is now reverse biased, so Vin gets cut off. The right diode has been forward biased this whole time, so current is flowing through it charging up the right capacitor. Current flows out of the left capacitor into the right capacitor until they equalize.

**Step 3**:
Vclk falls back to 0V. The top of the left capacitor falls back down too, allowing the left diode to be forward biased again. Current again flows from Vin into the left capacitor, charging it back up to 2V. The right diode is reversed biased now, so the right capacitor stays charged at 3V.

**Step 4**:
Vclk rises back to 1V. Left capacitor bumps up to 3V, again charging the right capacitor to 3V.

And so on and so on, repeating steps 3 and 4 forever, maintaining 3V on the right capacitor.

In real life, the components are non-ideal. So there are forward voltage drops across both diodes. This means the total voltage on the right capacitor, after steady-state is reached, will be:
$$V_{cap}=V_{in}+V_{clk_{high}}-2*V_d$$
Where Vd is the forward voltage drop of the diodes. Also, there is resistance in the circuit, which slows down the charge time of the capacitors, which affects the design choice for frequency and duty cycle.

Comment: Good explaination. But, you said, "So if the voltage on the bottom of the capacitor suddenly jumps to 1V, the 2V difference across the capacitor is preserved, and the top plate jumps up to 3V." My thought : By the time Vclk jump to 1v, the top plates of cap is positively charged and bottom plates of cap is negatively charged. When Vclk is go to 1v, it supply '+' charge on bottom plates of cap, so the negative charged plate gonna be weaken so its voltage would drop. Where am I wrong?

Comment: It looks like your confusion may be based on overly-simplified drawings of capacitors showing only positive charge on one plate and negative charge on the other. In reality, *both* plates have negative and positive charge carriers at all times. The top plate will simply have more positive charge carriers, making it more positive. The amount of charge carriers on the bottom plate will be driven by Vclk, which will add or remove charge carriers from the plate so that it is at either 0V or 1V relative to ground. Since this is an ideal circuit with no resistance, this will happen instantly.

Comment: Then, if i attach 2v voltage source on the left side of cap, and 1v source on the right side of cap, voltage of cap would 3v, too?

Comment: On the left and right side of the cap, between the two diodes? If I'm understanding you correct, no, you would not get 3V from that. Since this is an ideal circuit, an infinite amount of current would flow from the 2V source into the 1V source, which would cause the universe to explode.

Comment: no I just saying '2v source--cap---1v source' circuit... Sorry, but don't have any simulation program.. just want to check your logic is right in similar case

Comment: If you have 2V connected to one plate of the capacitor and 1V on the other, the voltage across the cap will be the difference of the two: 2V-1V=1V

Answer (score 0):

Neglecting the voltage drops across the diodes and assuming that all capacitors are discharged initially the following sequence takes place

1. Clk is low. The left capacitor is charged to 2V through D1.
2. Clk goes high. Vx is initially Vclk + 2V because the voltage at the bottom plate of the capacitor is now Vclk and the voltage across the capacitor is 2V. D1 is reverse biased and D2 is forward biased. The capacitor will discharge into the second capacitor. Vx is going to decrease.
3. Steps 1 and 2 repeat for each clock cycle and the left capacitor gets recharged to 2V while the right capacitor keeps its charge because of D2.
4. After a while the voltage at the second capacitor will be Vclk + 2V and Vx will move between 2V and Vclk + 2V.

Answer (score 0):

I just found yesterday this nice html5 graphic simulator, so I created a sim of your circuit, hopefully it helps you to see what is going on:

[your sim](http://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.200277308269968+50+5+50%0Av+624+256+624+176+0+0+40+2+0+0+0.5%0AR+736+400+624+400+0+2+40+1+0+0+0.5%0Ag+624+256+624+304+0%0Ad+624+176+736+176+1+0.805904783%0Ad+736+176+832+176+1+0.805904783%0Ac+736+272+736+176+0+0.00001+-2.4733609016427627%0Ac+832+176+832+272+0+0.00001+2.9623311570547726%0Aw+736+272+736+400+0%0Ag+832+272+832+304+0%0Aw+832+176+912+176+0%0AO+912+176+960+176+0%0Ar+896+176+896+272+0+100000%0Aw+896+272+832+272+0%0Ao+4+64+0+550+5+1.6+0+-1%0Ao+10+64+0+550+5+0.00009765625+1+-1%0A)

The 100K resistor is there just to provide a load so that the initial conditions are 0V on the output capacitor.